# JS - [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, semantic-ui

I'm developing a Laravel application, and trying to create a modal to fill a  table. I've added a `eventListener` to a select inside the modal. When I change the value of the select and it triggers the `eventListener`, the console show the error below:

> [Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'mousewheel' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952

I've tried many other ways to avoid this, but nothing worked. The code is below(don't know why, but the snippet isn't working). Can somebody wonder why this is happening?

```js
function addFuncionalidade() {
  console.log('updated')
  const value = $("#select-funcionalidade").val()
  console.log(value)
  $('#nome-funcionalidade').val(value)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.3.3/semantic.min.js"></script>

<div class="ui centered container">
    <button class="ui labeled icon button" onclick="$('#nova-funcionalidade').modal('show')">
        <i class="plus icon"></i>
        Acrescentar funcionalidade
    </button>
        
</div>
<div id="nova-funcionalidade" class="ui tiny modal">
    <div class="header">
        Inserir funcionalidade
    </div>
    <div class="centered scrolling content ui form">
        <div class="ui field">
            <label>Tipo</label>
            <select id="select-funcionalidade" onselect="addFuncionalidade()">
                <option value=1>Test 1</option>
                <option value=2>Test 2</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="ui field focus">
            <label>Nome</label>
            <input id="nome-funcionalidade" placeholder="Nome da funcionalidade"/>
        </div>
        <div class="ui field">
            <label>Descrição</label>
            <textarea id="descricao-funcionalidade" rows=3></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
            <button class="ui cancel button" onclick="$('#nova-funcionalidade').modal('hide')">Fechar</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your [mcve] doesn't seem to reproduce the described issue. It doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu, the code works, but don't know why the snippet doesn't, it doesn't show which error is occurring

Comment: Apparently `semantic.min.css` is bugged out. Can you repro in a jsfiddle? Or perhaps try to change to a previous version of `semantic`? This error will prolly get fixed, but you don't want to wait for it, do you?

Comment: This may be relevant: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/6233

Comment: It seems to be "unsolved" =/. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: I was dealing with similar issue, sometimes it's the 3rd party that is causing an issue. I created a package to deal with the issue: https://www.npmjs.com/package/passive-events-support
Make sure to just pass ['mousewheel'] to the library instead of using default event list